# How to update a contact's batch payment account name and details using the Xero API

Tags: c#, xero-api

I am able to add a sort code, account number and name to the batch payments field as can be seen below. But I am not able to update the "Bank account name" or "Details" fields using the API.

Currently I use `contact.BankAccountDetails = "678989 12345678 aj"` which works as seen.

I have tried setting `contact.BatchPayments` which has no effect.

The Xero docs are not helpful on this point.

[image: batch payments field on a contact]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot POST or PUT the Contact BatchPayments via the Xero API, you can only GET them.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/contacts

Comment: I am already posting the details above using the API. My question is about posting further information

Comment: You are updating a Contact with details that create default values for BatchPayments, not creating a BatchPayment, BatchPayments are not supported via the API. See https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/38129946

Comment: If you already knew that it wasn't possible, why on earth did you even bother asking the question?

Comment: Read the title, I am not asking that question. I'm asking about updating contact information.

Comment: According to the documentation, it's not possible. (See the link I posted)